# How to get Elasticsearch query result time in timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When I do a query on Elasticsearch (through Kibana dev tools) like below

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "node_id": "Abc"
    }
  }
}
```

I get the sample below result back. The result has a `ts` key which is in `date` format, not in timestamp format. How do I write a query so that this `ts` field is in timestamp? Is there a way to specify the format?

```
"_source" : {
          "organization_eid" : "Ga2",
          "node_id" : "Abc",
          "ts" : "2021-02-27T00:18:39.75226593Z
}
```

**Update**:

I added `docvalue_fields` above `_source` in the query. My entire query below:

```
GET _search
{
  "version": true,
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
    {
      "ts": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "ts",
      "format": "epoch_millis"
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "ts",
        "fixed_interval": "10m",
        "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "ts": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2021-03-03T00:30:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2021-03-03T12:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
  }
}
```

Now in the output, I see below (only showing `hits` section)

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "url.0.2_6_18689",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "...",
        "_version" : 1,
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "organization_eid" : "Ga2",
          "node_id" : "Abc",
          "ts" : "2021-03-03T11:59:30.705142021Z",
          "destination" : "....",
        "fields" : {
          "ts" : [
            "1614772770705"
          ]
```

As seen above, inside `fields` the `ts` is converted to `timestamp` but inside `_source` the `ts` is still in `datetime`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to leverage [doc values fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#docvalue-fields) in order to retrieve the raw timestamp value:

```
GET _search
{
  "docvalue_fields": [ "ts" ],                    <---- add this
  "_source": ["organization_eid", "node_id"],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "node_id": "Abc"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that does not work. I still see `ts` as date, not as timestamp epoch

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index please?

Comment: ES will never change the content of the `_source` document. You'll always see in `_source` whatever you send to ES. The only way to see a raw timestamp value is through `docvalue_fields`